# Persistent Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

`document.setbackground.bgcolor.value` certifiably works and stores a hex value (such a "000000" for black.  The script also works for changing the color of the background of the page when a new one is selected from a live form that updates the value.

My problem is that while my code stores a cookie with my browser, it does not work when I close the browser and reopen.  I want the background to start out as whatever was stored in the cookie.  Is there something wrong with my code or with my browser settings?

```
function setBackground () {
     if (document.setbackground.bgcolor.value != "none"){ 
          document.body.bgColor = "#" + document.setbackground.bgcolor.value;
          document.cookie = "bgColor=" + document.setbackground.bgcolor.value + 
               ";expires=Wednesday, 02-Mar-2020 12:00:00 GMT;";
     }
}
```

This code is embedded into the following HTML in the setPreference.js file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="setPreference.js"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#9999CC">
    <center>
    <form name="setbackground">
    Change background color?
    <select name="bgcolor" onchange="setBackground();" size="1">
        <option value="none">Select color</option>
        <option value="9999CC">Lavender</option>
        <option value="999966">Light Brown</option>
        <option value="66FFCC">Light Green</option>
        <option value="FFFFFF">White</option>    
    </select>
    </center>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and where are you loading it ?

Comment: I've updated to show the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

When user selects a item from `select` you'll set bgColor to its value and create a cookie.

**But you also need to load that cookie and set bgColor.**

You can use something simple like this (append it to your js):

```
// document.cookie - name1=value1; name2=value2; name3=value3

function GetCookie(what)
{
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(/; ?/g); // now we have array of name=value pairs
    for(var i in cookies)
    {
        var pair  = cookies.split("=", 1);
        var name  = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]);
        var value = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);

        if (name == what)
            return value;
    }
}

window.onload = function ()
{
    var color = GetCookie("bgColor"); // note that in the cookie can be ANY value as it comes from the user. So some condition to validate input wouldnt be bad idea
    document.setbackground.bgcolor.value = color;
    setBackground();
}
```